# Using two for loop to iterate two large list in python. Nothing happens

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I want to use two for loop to iterate two large lists, however nohting happens.
Here is the code

```
pfam = open(r'D:\RPS_data\pfam_annotations.tbl', 'r')
number = []
description = []
for j in pfam:
    number.append(j.split('\t')[0])
    description.append(j.split('\t')[-2])
print len(number),len(description)
for j in number:
    for r in description:
        if j==r:
            print 'ok'
else:
     print 'not match'
```

The result is:

```
D:\Pathyon\pathyon2.7\python.exe "D:/Biopython/Pycharm/Python Learning/war_battle/AUL-prediction/trash.py"
16230 16230

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My question is to find the same fraction in number and description. It is obvious that python does not run the for loop. Is it because I get two large lists? Anyone knows how to overcome this?

Comment: What do you expect? Should there be a number equal to a description in your data?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, My question is two lists are two big,when I want to use for loop, python does not run this.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I changed my question.

Comment: Please include a, minimal ( a few lines), sample of the data in the file.  How large is the file, how many lines??

Comment: @wwii  It seems that python does not run the for loop. I get else command in the code, if it runs, It will print "not match" or "ok"

Comment: Have you waited for the program to finish? There are 16230**2 =
263412900 loops, so it could take a while (some 20 seconds on my rather old machine with dummy integer data)

Comment: Yes, it is finished. @ThierryLathuille

Comment: You should sort 'number' and 'description' lists and perform a comparison between heads (as in a merge sort): it will be n.log(n) instead of n**2

Comment: It should always print `not match` because you never break out of the loop.

Comment: 1) `for ... else` is valid in python but it seems it's not correctly indented here 2) I think you want `zip(number, description)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, guys, It is the problem of my phycharm, I restarted it, everthing is ok.@ThierryLathuille

Comment: For each line in the file should the *number* and *description* column be the same?  Or can the *number* and *description* values be on different lines? You really should post a few lines of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your script to run a test. This is what I did: I inserted a dummy text blob as an `io.StringIO` file, and printed the resulting columns.

```
import io

annotations=u"""
1024\tmiddle\tkay\tend
3192\tmiddle\tdiana\tend
8675309\tmiddle\tjenny\tend
""".strip()

#pfam = open(r'D:\RPS_data\pfam_annotations.tbl', 'r')
pfam = io.StringIO(annotations)
number = []
description = []
for j in pfam:
    number.append(j.split('\t')[0])
    description.append(j.split('\t')[-2])
print len(number),len(description)
print number, description
for j in number:
    for r in description:
        if j==r:
            print 'ok'
else:
     print 'not match'
```

When I run this, the output is:

```
$ python2.7 test.py
3 3
[u'1024', u'3192', u'8675309'] [u'kay', u'diana', u'jenny']
not match
```

I'll argue that (1) your initial code appears to be working fine; and (2) Python is, in fact, running the second loop.

I am suspicious of your second loop. You are comparing *every* number against *every* description, using a direct comparison (`==`). Those both seem to be possible sources of error.

For example, are you sure you want to compare a number from line 1 (1024) with a description from line 3 (jenny)?

For example, are you sure you want to compare using equality? Are you looking for directly-equals, or containment. A "description" might contain several words, one of which was the number in question.